# Scheme Lambda expression with no parentheses around parameter

Tags: parameters, lambda, scheme, matrix-multiplication

I'm having trouble understanding this example of matrix multiplication in Scheme from Rosetta Code:

```
(define multiplyMatrices
    (lambda (matrix1 matrix2)
        (map (lambda (row)
            (apply map (lambda column
                (apply + (map * row column)))
            matrix2))
        matrix1)))
```

where `matrix1` and `matrix2` are each a list of lists. My question is this: Why is `column` on the fourth line not wrapped in parentheses?

As I understand it, a `lambda` expression is of the form `(lambda (<id1 id2 ...>) <exp>)`. From testing the code I know that it works and I know that wrapping `column` in parentheses does break the program, but I don't understand how the line is even syntactical and every explanation for `lambda` expressions I find online always describes them as I did above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but I want to point out that this isn't a special syntax, but rather a specific case of a more general syntax involving a *rest parameter*.

Consider the following functions:

```
(lambda () ...)
(lambda (first) ...)
(lambda (first second) ...)
(lambda (first second third) ...)
```

These functions take 0, 1, 2, and 3 arguments, respectively.

Now consider these functions:

```
(lambda rest ...)
(lambda (first . rest) ...)
(lambda (first second . rest) ...)
(lambda (first second third . rest) ...)
```

These functions take *at least* 0, 1, 2, and 3 arguments, respectively. Any further arguments are collected into a list and bound to `rest`, in these cases.

The first set of functions use *proper lists* as their lambda lists. The second set of functions use *improper lists* as their lambda lists. So what's the distinction between the two? **A proper list is simply a list that has `()` as its final cdr, and an improper list is a list that has something else as its final cdr.** It's that simple.

To give greater visual symmetry between the two sets of functions, the first set of functions could be written this way:

```
(lambda () ...)
(lambda (first . ()) ...)
(lambda (first second . ()) ...)
(lambda (first second third . ()) ...)
```

The list `(first second third)` is *exactly* the same as `(first second third . ())`. Once these expressions are read in, there is *no way* to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax puts all the parameters into a list:

```
(define test (lambda x x))

(test 1)
=> '(1)

(test 1 2 3)
=> '(1 2 3)

(test '(1 2 3))
=> '((1 2 3))
```

See also [here](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding%3ah2): "*If formals is a single variable (not in a list), e.g., z, it is bound to a list of the actual parameters.*"

Answer (score 0):

Notice the difference between the following two functions:

```
> (define f1 (lambda (x) x))
> (f1 "HELLO")
"HELLO"
```

and

```
> (define f2 (lambda y y))    
> (f2 "HELLO")
'("HELLO")
```

When a function is called in scheme, the arguments are bound to the function's parameter list. Since `f1`'s argument list is `(x)` (with parenthesis around it,) the list is *destructured*, so `x` refers to the one argument in the list that was passed to it.

`f2` does not include parenthesis around its argument list, `y`, so the argument list sent to it is not destructured, so the list is returned.